# How to shift rows in Laravel Eloquent?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I have a table like this:

```
+--------+-------------------+-----------+
| ID     | Type              |  Order    |
+--------+-------------------+-----------+
| 1      | A                 | 0         |
| 2      | A                 | 1         |
| 3      | A                 | 2         |
| 4      | B                 | 0         |
| 5      | B                 | 1         |
| 6      | B                 | 2         |
| 7      | B                 | 3         |
| 8      | B                 | 4         |
| 9      | C                 | 0         |
| 10     | C                 | 1         |
+--------+-------------------+-----------+
```

Using Laravel Eloquent:

```
$list = Type::where('Type', '=', 'B')
    ->where('Order', '=', '2');

$list->delete();
```

If I do the above, I get the following:

```
+--------+-------------------+-----------+
| ID     | Type              |  Order    |
+--------+-------------------+-----------+
| 1      | A                 | 0         |
| 2      | A                 | 1         |
| 3      | A                 | 2         |
| 4      | B                 | 0         |
| 5      | B                 | 1         |
| 7      | B                 | 3         | <- notice the Order 2 row is gone
| 8      | B                 | 4         |
| 9      | C                 | 0         |
| 10     | C                 | 1         |
+--------+-------------------+-----------+
```

How can I make it so the Order shifts accordingly for Type B, so it looks like this?

```
+--------+-------------------+-----------+
| ID     | Type              |  Order    |
+--------+-------------------+-----------+
| 1      | A                 | 0         |
| 2      | A                 | 1         |
| 3      | A                 | 2         |
| 4      | B                 | 0         |
| 5      | B                 | 1         |
| 7      | B                 | 2         |
| 8      | B                 | 3         |
| 9      | C                 | 0         |
| 10     | C                 | 1         |
+--------+-------------------+-----------+
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Database-wise you need to run these two queries to recalculate values in the `order` column

```sql
DELETE FROM types WHERE type='B' AND `order`=2;
UPDATE types SET `order` = `order` - 1 WHERE type='B' AND `order` > 2;
```

Here is a **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0eb29/1)** demo

---

Now in Eloquent it may look like this

```
DB::transaction(function()
{
    Type::where('type', '=', 'B')
        ->where('order', '=', 2)
        ->delete();

    Type::where('type', '=', 'B')
        ->where('order', '>', 2)
        ->update(['order' => DB::raw('`order` - 1')]);
});
```